# Передача List<> в класс

Tags: c#, winforms, list

Как передать значения `List<string> scriptsToRun` в другой клас (в метод `runQueries`)?

Отсюда:

```
private void ExecAllSkrypty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] dir = Directory.GetFiles(skryptyDirBox.Text);

            List<string> scriptsToRun = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in dir)
            {
                string query = File.ReadAllText(item);
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(item);
                scriptsToRun.Add(fileName);
            }
            GetRunner().runQueries(fileName, query);
        }
```

Сюда:

```
public void runQueries(string sName, string query)
        {
            using (var c = new Context(connection,true))
            {
                var scriptRunned = c.Scripts.Where(x => scriptsToRun.Contains(x.ScriptName)).Select(s => s.ScriptName).ToList();

                scriptsToRun.RemoveAll(s => scriptRunned.Contains(s));

                foreach (var sname in scriptRunned)
                {
                    //read the file sname
                    Insertquery(sname,query);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: А просто добавить параметр в метод Вас не устраивает?

Comment: Ну перенесите `runQueries` внутрь цикла. Вы код не сами писали, что ли?

Comment: @VladD внутрь цикла не получится, надо будет метод менять, т.к. он там еще над этими данными проводит операцию `scriptsToRun.RemoveAll(s => scriptRunned.Contains(s));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи значений добавьте в список аргументов метода `runQueries` третий агрумент

```
public void runQueries(string sName, string query, List<string> scriptsToRun)
```

И при вызове метода передавайте

```
GetRunner().runQueries(fileName, query, scriptsToRun);
```